# css to checkboxlist control in accordion menu in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, css, accordion, checkboxlist

I want to change the default style of checkboxlist available in websforms, I can apply changes to the text but cant change the checkbox which looks better and appealing.

```
<div id="left_columnforSale">   
 <asp:Accordion ID="Accordion1" runat="server" SelectedIndex="0" HeaderCssClass="accordHeader" ContentCssClass="accordContent" HeaderSelectedCssClass="accordHeaderSelected"
           AutoSize="None"
            FadeTransitions="true"
            TransitionDuration="50"
            FramesPerSecond="20"
            RequireOpenedPane="false"
            SuppressHeaderPostbacks="True">
            <Panes>
              <asp:AccordionPane>
               <Header>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;CheckListBox
                </Header>
                 <Content>
                    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="chkbox">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0 AND 1000">0 - £1,000</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1000 AND 2000">£1,000 - £2,000</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2000 AND 3000">£2,000 - £3,000</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="3000 AND 4000">£3,000 - £4,000</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="4000 AND 5000">£4,000 - £5,000</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="5000 AND 6000">£5,000 - £6,000</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="6000 AND 7000">£6,000 - £7,000</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="7000 AND 8000">£7,000 - £8,000</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="8000 AND 9000">£8,000 - £9,000</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="9000 AND 10000">£9,000 - £10,000</asp:ListItem>

                    </asp:CheckBoxList>

                </Content>

            </asp:AccordionPane>

            </Panes>
 </asp:Accordion>
```

CSS:

```
#left_columnforSale .accordContent
{
color: #999999;
font-size: 11px;

}
#left_columnforSale .accordContent .chkbox td:hover
{
color: #606060;
text-decoration: underline;
cursor: pointer;
 }
```

Any tutoria;l or help will be appreciated
thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, note that checkboxes are far from flexible. Browsers don't let you style them that much with CSS. Any pure-css solution that you won't change the look of your checkboxes that much... For any serious style change, you will have to code something in javascript that acts like a checkbox.

If your changes are minor / can be done in css :

If you want to style all checkboxes directly in your css, use the following code :

```
input[type="checkbox"]{
    /* Here are the styles that will be applied to ALL checkboxes */
}
```

Now if you want something particular for some checkboxes, you can go with classes. By applying a CSS class to your checkbox directly. CssClass is a property for standard web controls in ASP.NET so you can apply it to

```
<asp:ListItem CssClass="checkbox" Value="0 AND 1000">0 - £1,000</asp:ListItem>
```

for example.

From there, in your css

```
.checkbox {
    /* Here are the styles that apply to checkboxes that have the checkbox css class */
}
```

If you can't do it with CSS : 
Here are a couple of examples of what you can do with javascript / css : 
http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettycheckboxes/
http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

Comment: hi , i tried ur input[type="checkbox"]{
    /* Here are the styles that will be applied to ALL checkboxes */
}

Comment: input[type="checkbox"]
{
    color: #606060;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}

Comment: i will also try the above jquery examples later on , just scratching my head .. have been working for d last 3 hours to figure out the styling checkboxlist through css

Comment: you can't style the text using input[type="checkbox"], it's really for styling the box. As I said though, browsers won't let you style checkboxes that much. For major changes, go with js